# How to handle Django-PostgreSQL Locks

Tags: django, postgresql, locking, celery

I've a problem with a Django project with postgresql backend.

I know that there're some open issues about it in "web transaction". Every time I do a select, a new lock is created in postgresql. That lock is fine in web interactions (request - process - response)

What it seems to be a problem is that I've some trouble with celery integration. I've some tasks that takes too long to perform, and they are something as follows:

```
l1. instances = mymodels.MyModel.objects.all()
l2. for instance in instances:
l3.     do something with that instance (not update, just performing 
l4.     some operations from instance fields)
```

The lock is only released when that task ends. Is there any way that the generated lock releases after "l1"?

Output of my postgres locking tables

```
SELECT locktype, relation::regclass, mode, transactionid AS tid,
virtualtransaction AS vtid, pid, granted
FROM pg_catalog.pg_locks l LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_database db
ON db.oid = l.database WHERE (db.datname = 'sandbox' OR db.datname IS NULL)
AND NOT pid = pg_backend_pid();


  locktype  | relation |     mode      | tid | vtid  |  pid  | granted 
------------+----------+---------------+-----+-------+-------+---------
 virtualxid |          | ExclusiveLock |     | 3/427 | 47715 | t
(1 row)
```

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that this is part of Django - driver behaviour, without explicitly setting autocommit. With autocommit = True, all the queries starts and ends at the moment of its evaluation.

I know that it's not safe in terms of query + update, but most of time, queries are only that... queries

Cheers